# Generalization of Eight Queen Puzzle

Tags: code-challenge, fastest-code, chess

Here's one generalized version of the famous [Eight Queen's Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle):

> Given an `n` × `n` chess board, and an integer `m` (≤ `n`). Find all possible ways to put `nm` Queens such that
>
> - there are `m` Queens at each **row**
> - there are `m` Queens at each **column**
>
> (note that we do not impose any restriction on the diagonals).

---

As you might see, it is possible, e.g. [`1` denotes a Queen]:

#### `n` = 3, `m` = 2

```
1   1   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
```

#### `n` = 15, `m` = 2

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
```

---

**Input:** `n`, `m`

**Output:** Number of solutions

**Winning Criteria:** Single thread, Fastest [I will test with `n` = 15, `m` = 8 in my computer]

*Optional:* Print all solutions (as in the format given in examples)

*Preferred Language:* Python 2.7, Julia

Good luck!

Comment: Back of the envelope suggests about `10^50` solutions for `n = 15, m = 8`.

Comment: This is the third time today I've run into this problem. The world is a funny place.

Comment: @xnor, it's 649920606971625785993833472182540933121831448000. Pretty good estimate.

Comment: I find it quite distracting to call this a generalisation of the eight queens problem. It would make slightly more sense to call it a generalisation of the eight rooks problem, but the literature ([A008300](http://oeis.org/A008300) and see refs.) seems to describe the problem principally in terms of 0-1 matrices. It's clear that printing all solutions is a non-goer for all but some very small inputs, so I would remove that suggestion.